# Uppy IO Resume-able File Upload allowedFileTypes

Tags: javascript, resume-upload, tus

I'm using Uppy.io v0.23.1 for resumeable file uploads.

As per [documentation](https://uppy.io/docs/uppy/#restrictions), we can limit file types through `allowedFileTypes` property.

Here is my code in effort to limit file uploader control to only allow MS PowerPoint files:

```
var uppy = new Uppy.Core({
    debug: true, autoProceed: false, restrictions: {
        maxFileSize: 100000,            
        allowedFileTypes: ['.pptx']
    } });
uppy.use(Uppy.Dashboard, {
    trigger: '.UppyModalOpenerBtn',
    inline: true,
    target: '.DashboardContainer'


});
```

**Error:** You can only upload: .pptx

**Note:** Setting mime type like ['application/zip'] accepts PPTX files but it also allows ZIP files as well. 
Also tried `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation` as mime type for PPTX. But this doesn't even allow PPTX files.

Any solution or workaround would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An issue was created on [GitHub](https://github.com/transloadit/uppy/issues/1340) as well.

Member of repository suggested that...

> 0.23 is a very old version that doesn't support extensions at all, only mime types. Extension support was added in a 0.25.x version. You would need to update (ideally to 0.30 if possible) to be able to use allowedFileTypes: ['.ext']